# THE taking the bull by the horns

Tags: grammar, definite-articles, gerunds

There is "taking the bull by the horns" and "the taking of
the bull by the horns" is not incorrect.
But may there be
"**the** taking the bull by the horns"? That is to ask, does the
direct object *the bull …* (instead of the prepositional phrase *of the bull …*) somehow
preclude the article in front of 'taking'? 
A negative answer should contain a proof of sorts.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "preclude the preposition"? Or maybe "mandate the preposition"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, no, see if new parenthesis clarifies.

Comment: In that case, your question isn't clear, because the definite article appears in all your alternatives.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, sorry, I meant the first one, in front of 'taking'.

Comment: What in the world does that title mean?

Comment: φ is a variable, it means any verb.

Comment: @Lawrence φ on you for using weird letters in your title ;)

Comment: There is no prepositional phrase **by the bull**. Do you mean "by the horns"? You need to use a paragraph for your question to read better. Be as clear and specific as possible when you ask a question.

Comment: Don't use an idiom as your example. Use a full sentence, something boring, and without unnecessary modifiers. 'He is driving the car badly', 'His driving of the car was bad','His driving the car was bad', '*The driving the car was bad' (the last one is not right). Also noun phrases don't necessarily allow articles. 'My car', '*The my car'. 'What he said is wrong', '*The what he said is wrong'. Also re prima facie, [you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+prima+facie)

Comment: @Rathony, you mean put every sentence in a separate paragraph? how does that help?

Comment: It is better than not using it at all.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the syntax of English nominalizations, it should be either "the taking of the bull ..." or "taking the bull ...", but *"the taking the bull ..." or *"(no article) taking of the bull ...".  This is because "taking" may either be a noun derived from the verb "take" or it may be a gerund form of that verb (hence a verb).  And nouns take articles but not direct objects, while verbs take direct objects but not articles.  (Actually "the taking the bull ..." sounds pretty good to me, though I'd predict it is ungrammatical.)

We can confirm the pattern by constructing examples with adjectives or adverbs, since another difference between nouns and adjectives is that nouns take adjective modifiers but verbs take adverb modifiers:

```
the immediate taking of the bull by the horns
immediately taking the bull by the horns  
*the immediately taking of the bull by the horns
```

Comment: I know of only one theory of why a noun derived from a verb cannot take a direct object, which is my theory of 2psg, outlined here on the linguistics SE: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17271/how-can-psg-describe-the-vertical-dimension-of-sentence-structure.  In short, all phrase types have an obliqueness level; lower level constituents can't contain higher level ones, and derived nominalizations (S3) are more obligue than direct objects (NP2).